# Why does an aircraft have to be flying straight and level to facilitate a jump?

Tags: parachute

In the other questions about parachutes on this site, it has been stated that the aircraft would have to be flying straight and level to facilitate a jump. However, there were quite a few pilots during WWII whose planes were not flying straight and level and who still managed to escape.

Is there a difference between then and now that I am not catching?

Comment: I would add that a lot of the WWII pilots did **not** escape as well, and this is part of why we say that it should be straight and level.

Answer (score 6):

One of the reasons why many WW2 pilots did not make it out were the **G-forces and acceleration in directions other than the door when they had to get out**. The bailing out survival rate appears to be correlated to the ease of exit.

If you're going to have a smooth and safe departure, you're happiest doing it during level flight when there's no interference from plane motion.

[image: bail]
<sub>(source: [lonesentry.com](http://www.lonesentry.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2010/10/bail-out-b17-bomber-bailout.jpg))</sub>

[image: fire]

Comment: Note that you don't necessarily *have* to be flying straight and level: you could conceivably be in a controlled turn, climb, and *maybe* even a slight descent and still get out (the key is "controlled", and not subject to crazy acceleration/G loading). For a novice jumper though straight-and-level unaccelerated flight is the safest jump configuration, and the one most likely to result in a successful egress.

Comment: Is there any context for the second photo? I'm not sure what it illustrates aside from a plane you wanna bail out of.